# Use command to move cursor like `^` and `$`, in NeoVim?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

As title. How to move the cursor with vim command `:...`? I want to make a toggle that achieves this behavior but I didn't find anywhere this is explained :(

Answer (score 1):

Any of

- `:normal! ^` (or `0`, or `$`)
- the functions `setpos`, `cursor`, or `setcursorcharpos`

should do it.

OTOH, on the `:` line you need things like `<C-b>` and `<C-e>` (see `:help cmdline-editing`), or press `<C-f>` and use normal motions.

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

This ternary version for `0 ^ $` is much better. Please call me UX-magician :)

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '0', '<cmd>lua toggle_zero_goto_line_beginning()<CR>', NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
local __goto_line_beginning_value = 0
function _G.toggle_zero_goto_line_beginning()
  if (__goto_line_beginning_value == 0) then
    vim.cmd("exe 'normal! 0'")
    __goto_line_beginning_value = 1
  elseif (__goto_line_beginning_value == 1) then
    vim.cmd("exe 'normal! ^'")
    __goto_line_beginning_value = 2
  else
    vim.cmd("exe 'normal! $'")
    __goto_line_beginning_value = 0
  end
end
```

---

### Old one

I just tried-n-error in Vim and turn it into neovim version:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('n', '0', '<cmd>lua toggle_zero_goto_line_beginning()<CR>', NOREF_NOERR_TRUNC)
local __at_beginning = false
function _G.toggle_zero_goto_line_beginning()
  if (not __at_beginning) then
    vim.cmd("exe 'normal! ^'")
    __at_beginning = true
  else
    vim.cmd("exe 'normal! $'")
    __at_beginning = false
  end
end
```